# Help ---- SQL Script

Tags: sql-server

Store No Store Name Region Division Q10(response) Q21(response)

2345          ABC                      North Test                 1                                     5
2345                                             North Test                  6                                     3
2345            ABC                      North Test                  4                                    6

1st calculation

1 ) Engaged(%) = Response Greater than 4.5
       3 (total response greater than 4.5) / 6 (total count)  *  100  =  50%

Store No Store Name Region Division Q10 Q21
2345                ABC               North Test            1        5
2345                ABC              North Test           6        3
2345               ABC               North Test            4       6

2) not engaged (%) = Response less than 2
     1 (total response less than 2) /  6 (total count)  *  100  =  16.66%

I should be able to get the table like this

Store No Store Name Region Division Engaged(%) Disengaged(%)
2345              ABC               North Test                  50                          16.66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statistics rounded 2 digits after point (T-SQL), grouped by stores:

```
SELECT
    store_no,
    store_name,
    region,
    division,
    ROUND( CAST( (SUM(CASE WHEN q10 > 4.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN q21 > 4.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS FLOAT) / (COUNT(q10)+COUNT(q21)) * 100, 2)   AS engaged,
    ROUND( CAST( (SUM(CASE WHEN q10 < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN q21 < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS FLOAT) / (COUNT(q10)+COUNT(q21)) * 100, 2)  AS not_engaged
FROM
    yourtable
GROUP BY
    store_no,
    store_name,
    region,
    division
```

Comment: +1 That should do it. Note on `COUNT(*)*2` - it ignores NULLs; if these need to be handled better write it as `COUNT(q10)+COUNT(q21)`